# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() When show array data

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Data insert an array  successfully but when I show it doesn't appear. I need it to show nested foreach loop. Others data shows  but the array data doesn't. I have some job post and some job can be  under some job industry(category like accounting , financial). Where to change it to solve this issue I couldn't find it. I already try all possible solution.

I want to show a job multiple category/ industry. The array insert like is

```
["2","4","5"]
```

But it doesn't show , if the value like this  2(number) then its ok and show. "Print_r($allJobs)" also show just 2nd data not array.

This is my Controller :

```
 public function index(){
        $allJobs = DB::table('jobs')
                ->join('companies','companies.id','=','jobs.comp_id')
                ->join('job_industries','job_industries.id','=','jobs.industry_id')
                ->join('job_types','job_types.id','=','jobs.job_type_id')
                ->join('districts','districts.id','=','jobs.district')
            ->where('jobs.status','=',1)
            ->select('jobs.*','companies.company_name','job_types.job_type','job_industries.industry_name','districts.name as disName')
            ->orderBy('jobs.id','desc')
            ->paginate(10);
            return view('backEnd.job.jobList',['allJobs' => $allJobs]);    
    }
```

My Model:

```
class Job extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'comp_id', 'emp_id', 'industry_id','job_type_id','title','vacancy','job_context','responsibility','requirement','salary','add_info',
        'edu_requirement', 'experience','facility','division','district','app_info','deadline','image','status'
    ];
    protected $casts = [
        'industry_id' => 'array',

    ];

    public function getDataAttribute($value)
    {
        return json_decode($value, true);
    }

}
```

My View :

```
  @php
    $i =1;
     @endphp
                
      @foreach($allJobs as $allJob)
                
     <tr>
    <td>{{$i++}}</td>
    <td>{{$allJob->title}}</td>
     <td>{{$allJob->job_type}}</td>
     <td>
     @if (is_array($allJob) || is_object($allJob)){
@foreach(json_decode($allJob->industry_id, true) as $key => $value)
             {{ $loop->parent->first ? '' : ', ' }}
                <span><strong>{{  $value }}</strong></span>
             @endforeach
          @endif           
     </td>
     <td>{{$allJob->company_name}}</td>
     <td>{{$allJob->disName}}</td>
      <td>{{$allJob->deadline}}</td>
                 
     </td>
    </tr>
      @endforeach
```

Comment: `<option value="#">...</option>` `#` is a value... For that validation to work, you need to do `<option value="">...</option>` (Blank)

Comment: Or, you could use `'skill_name' =>'required|not_in:#',` to ignore the default value (`#`); either approach should work.

Comment: Its not working. I update my question.

Comment: @MM_Chanchal is the rules are correct? as i see differences in form field names and properties in the rules function

Comment: You have to use the `name` attribute properly... You have these names: `txt_reading`, `txt_writing`, and `txt_speaking`, but your rules are `reading`, `writing` and `speaking`. **Those do not match**. Your rules should be `'txt_reading' => 'required'`, `'txt_writing' => 'required'` and `'txt_speaking' => 'required'` (you don't need the `not_in` rule anymore)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `<select>` tag will take input based on the options. Since your options are {Select},{High},{Medium},{Low}, it takes the Default value as {Select} which is pre-selected.

**Try this code**

```
<select name="txt_speaking" id="" class="form-control">
                   <option disabled>Select</option> //changes here
                   <option value="High">High</option>
                   <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
                     <option value="Low">Low</option>
                 </select>
```

`disabled` makes sure that the disabled option is not submitted.
`readonly` does not allow selecting that option (or making any other changes), but it does sumbit the value

More infomation here

[Read here(Last line as Note)](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_readonly.asp#:%7E:text=%20HTML%20%3Cinput%3E%20readonly%20Attribute%20%201%20Definition,the%20attribute.%20%203%20Syntax.%20%20More%20)

Comment: Try these changes, and validate again. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score -1):

```
<form role="form" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm('addsstatus')" class="addsstatus" action="{{url('admin-user/variante')}}" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
<div class="box-body">
<div class="last_row" id="criteria1">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="">Variante Type</label>
<select class="form-control select2 "  name="variante_type_id" style="width: 100%;" id="variante_type_id">
<option value="">--Select --</option>
@foreach($varianteType as $varianteTypes)
<option value="{{$varianteTypes->id}}" >{{$varianteTypes->name}}</option>>
@endforeach
</select>
</div>
@error('variante_type_id')
<div class="alert">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="">Variente Name<span class="require label-mandatory">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" class="form-control input-mandatory" placeholder="Enter Variente Name">
</div>
@error('name')
<div class="alert">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="">Variente Unit</label>
<input type="text" name="unit" id="unit" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Variente Unit">
</div>
@error('unit')
<div class="alert">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center;">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-main">Submit</button>
<span class="btn btn-default reset">Clear</span>
<a href="{{url('admin-user/variante')}}" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>

Controller Validation
$validate = Validator::make($request->all(),[
'name'          => 'required',
'variante_type_id'          => 'required',
]);
if($validate->fails()){

return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validate);
}
```